# Как выйти из github Desktop?

Tags: github

Как выйти из github Desktop????

Comment: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/6173

Comment: Я думала, только с вимом такие проблемы бывают... В настройках вкладка "Аккаунт", там кнопочка "Sign Out" - если ваш вопрос был про это.

Answer (score 1):

Нажать на крестик в верхнем правом углу программы. Можно через диспетчер задач (ctrl+shift+esc или ctrl+alt+del).